# Slip left in water to take root for too long

Tags: plant-health, propagation, cuttings, morning-glory, recovery

I have left a large healthy Morning Glory (not sure if *Ipomoea macrantha* or *Ipomoea violacea*) slip in a cup of mineral water for it to take root. But I delayed to plant it for many days and now it is pale and burnt, but roots still looking pretty healthy and one big leaf still enduring. It seems able to survive, if properly taken care.

Now I have just planted it in a pot and my question is: is there anything I can do from now on to increase its chances of survival and/or to speed its health's recovery?

It took long for it to take root an I have cut it during a special occasion and from a dangerous place, so keeping it alive is highly preferable to simply trying again.

Answer (score 2):

Look carefully at the join of the one leaf stalk and the stem. If there is a sign of growth in there then you may be in luck. With your rooted leaf in a moist planting compost, trim off what is clearly dead or dying and keep warm and minimally watered in filtered light and you might just get lucky. If not, at least an important lesson learned.

You might want to examine the quality of the water you used for rooting. In warm weather Ipomoea from young fresh green shoots should strike roots in a few days, not more. It is possible your water contains minerals or chemicals that slow the development of roots.

Comment: Should I cut all the leaves if all of them are looking sick, given there are indeed some wannabe new stalks? And I used mineral water precisely because I was afraid tap water would do harm. I suppose it took long because I'm on the southern hemisphere, it is almost winter here, now